# Understanding operators in for loops in Python 3

Tags: python

I have the following code as apart of IBM ETL cert as an exercise and do not understand how part of the code works.

Code:

```
    def freqAll(self):        
            # split text into words
            wordList = self.fmtText.split(' ')
            
            # Create dictionary
            freqMap = {}
            for word in set(wordList): # use set to remove duplicates 
freqMap[word] = wordList.count(word)
        
        return freqMap
```

In the block that creates the dictionary the code in the for loop says

```
for word in set(wordList):
```

how does python know that "word" is in the word list? There is no part of the code that defines "word" as anything...

Comment: `for [variablename] in [iterable]` is its own explicit syntactic construct, which defines a for loop. When not used in this context, `[object] in [collection]` is also an operator for determining whether something is a member of a collection. The python interpreter considers them to be entirely different and generally unambiguous.

Comment: What other programming languages are you familiar with? Java offers the for-each loop `for (int i: nums)` which is similar to the Python code above.

Comment: Please note that creating an empty dictionary, then looping over an iterable and setting keys in the dictionary is where a dictionary comprehension shines. `freqMap = { word: wordList.count(word) for word in set(wordList) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word` is just a variable. You can use any other variable instead of `word`.

`word` is a temporary variable used to store the value of the current position in the range of items of the `for` loop that only has scope within its `for` loop. You could use any other variable name in place of `word` such as `count` or `items` or just an `i`.

Comment: ah i think i understand. So word can just be jibberish if i really wanted it to be? in this usecase even if i used 'duck; instead but it would have iterated through the same list and returned the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

when you type `for word in set(wordList):` it is implicitly doing the check.

`word` is the variable that stores the word that is being read at that moment, and `wordList` is the list where you have saved all the words that you are going to read.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0234/
https://www.learnpython.org/es/Loops

Answer (score 0):

For loops in Python work differently to those in most other languages. Instead of incrementing a counter, they loop over an "iterable", which can be a list, a set, a range, or many other elements.

For each iteration of the loop, Python asks the term to the right of the `in` for the next value, and binds that to the variable name on the left of it. Therefore, that word can be any variable name. It keeps asking for the next value to bind to the variable until the thing on the right runs out of items. At that point, Python ends the loop and continues on with the rest of the code.